# Null & Residual Deviance in GLM in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, deviance

For a GLM in R, is it correct to interpret that Higher the difference between NULL & RESIDUAL deviance, better is your model? If not, then how do i know if my model is good or bad (for GLM - poisson, gamma, tweedie)

Answer (score 1):

Simply check your model using `anova.glm()` with a F test or a Chi-squared test. If your write `anova(model,test="F")` this will automatically compare it to a null model and send back a p-value. Check Zuur et al. 2009 and, in R, `?anova.glm`